# .Net Deserialize XML, Determine if element not present

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have objects that are being serialized and want to add a "version" property.

What I'd like is for:

1. New objects that are created in code should be given the "latest" version (defined somewhere)
2. Objects deserialized, that *don't* have the version property in their xml, should be labeled as "version 1".
3. Objects deserialized, that *do* have the version property in their xml, should use whatever version is in the xml.

Example (psuedo-code):

```
const string LatestVersion = "2";
class Foo {
   public String version {get; set; }
}

var foo = new Foo();
foo.version == "2"
serialize(foo) ->  "<foo><version>2</version></foo>";

foo = deserialize("<foo></foo>")
foo.version == "1";

foo = deserialize("<foo><version>2</version>");
foo.version == "2";

foo = deserialize("<foo><version>3</version>");
foo.version == "3";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public bool versionSpecified {get;set;}
```

You should find this gets set to true (by XmlSerializer itself) when it has a value. Watch out though: it also needs to *report* true during serialization, else the value is not included.

---

Perhaps an easier way:

```
private string _version;
public string version {
    get { return _version ?? "1"; } // the default value
    set { _version = value; }
}
```

Then check if the field is null.

Comment: The problem with this is when somebody creates an instance they'll need to set the version.  I was hoping to set the version to the latest version in the constructor.